# iOS .ipa Distribution Method for Airwatch MDM

Tags: ios, mdm, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution, airwatch

Our company has an ios application and we want to distribute the application to different companies without putting the app in the App Store.  Some of our customers  have an Airwatch MDM and want to distribute our application inside their company.

We prepared the ipa with adhoc method and sent the ipa file to a customer. However, the customer told us that the file could not be installed. In this situation it is our belief that each customer should re-sign this ipa file with their own provision profile. After that they should put the application to their mdm with their resigned ipa. Am i right or is there something missing here?

Actually when I made a search on the internet there is one more method called enterprise distribution. Enterprise distribution confused my mind. In order to send my ipa to each customer for MDM, do I need to have an enteprise account?  Or do customers need it? I have a trouble about which method should I export the ipa to make my customer distribute it via MDM.I would be glad if someone helps me about this issue. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you should use B2B distribution. You upload the app to AppStore Connect as usual, but in the pricing and availability screen you make the app available privately through Apple Business Manager. You will need your customers Apple Business Manager organisation identifiers. To use enterprise distribution your customers would each need an enterprise agreement with Apple. It is expensive and complex for them to use compared to B2B

Comment: You should watch this WWDC session https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/